# SSIS Sequence Container

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl

I am new in `SSIS` developing and i am following some tutorial in order to get familiar with `SSIS`.

Right now i am messing with the `Sequence Container` and i understand that is used as a subset of the `SSIS` package in the control flow and it can contain zero or more tasks and containers.

So in the example that i am looking for i have 3 tasks, the two of them are inside in container and i am implemnting a logic `(A and B) AND C` as the tutorial says the `Sequence Container` is used to create a logic `(A and B)`.

My Question is: How can i implement a logic of `(A OR B) AND C` ?

For a better clarification see the image below to understand the logic

[image]

Right now the logic is `(A AND B) AND C`.

So is there a way to do `(A OR B) AND C` ?

Comment: Do Tasks (A or B) and C need to execute at the same time?  Or can Task C execute after A or B without issue?

Comment: @iamdave it is a simple example so i guess they execute at the same time

Comment: Being honest I don't think this is something that ever comes up in such generic terms.  There would normally be some degree of precedence or logic that states *Try this one, and then that one, and then this other one.*  Having a generic *If either of these succeed when run at the same time* doesn't really have that many use cases.

Comment: @iamdave i am not sure what you exactly meant with that...

Comment: I mean that the ability to do what you are asking is not immediately obvious because it generally isn't ever put into practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a combination of conditional connectors and a dummy sequence box will achieve the effect :

1. connect A and B to a sequence box and edit the connector to be a
   logical OR
2. connect the output of the sequence box to D
3. connect the output of C to D

Comment: By sequence box you meant `Sequence Container`? Maybe can you post an image because i am not sure if i understand your step 1

Comment: Yes, I mean sequence container; for the first step you need to right click on one of the connectors, then edit and then select logical OR. I don't have VS on the machine I'm now but will post a picture as soon as I can.

Comment: No worries i understand what you meant thank you for time!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your design, you can just increase the `maximumErrorCount` of your sequence container to 2.
So, if you have 1 error on a script task A or B , the container keeps success. But if both failed, the container failed too.

[image]

**Edit:**
Providing an image example of Jayvee answser implementation:
[image]

Comment: Whilst this works for the question given, I think it is a poor design choice as the functionality is not obvious in the designer and may cause issues in the future if the container has additional or different logic added to suit changing processes.

Comment: It is a solution but i don't think can work on larger applications.